# Start/Stop times of Linux PC

Tags: boot, systemd, last

I would like to see the start/stop times of a Linux PC.

I found this command, but the output is wrong:

```
last reboot -F
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-46-generi Thu Mar 14 10:04:27 2019 - Thu Mar 14 15:31:11 2019  (05:26)
```

That's not true. Instead of 10:04 it is 09:04.

See related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/854567/last-reboot-is-missing-one-hour/859782

How can I see the correct start/stop times on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Any chance the reboot was during Daylight saving time and clock  was adjusted one hour?

Comment: @Dextro67 I did not change the clock by hand, and the wrong output of the `reboot` commands happens every day. I don't care for the internals, I just want reliable numbers.

Comment: Then set the system time zone to UTC.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I need to change the system time zone, just to be able to get the start/stop times reliably? OK, this was new to me.

Comment: @guettli Please, **do not cross post**. [You've already asked the same question ~2 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854567/last-reboot-is-missing-one-hour/859782).

Comment: What timezone set on this box?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev does this matter? I want a solution which works with any time zone. AFAIK it is CET.

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: @ewwhite the start/stop times get logged by a custom tool at my job (attendance clock) If the custom tool fails, then you need to adjust the values by hand. I want simple way to get these values if the custom tool fails.

Comment: I don't know if the start and stop times of a PC is a good and deterministic way of acquiring this information, but the answer below seems to provide what you need.

Comment: @ewwhite I agree, start/stop times are not  a good solution for this. But that's the way it is. This is not part of the question. I just want a solution for the current situation. And I am happy, since I found a solution. There are more important things for me than "start/stop times are not  a good solution for this".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# timestamps corresponds to your current timezone
user@node:~$ journalctl --list-boots
-3 0f2fcb9569384a2aa2d5492505f86cda Tue 2018-11-27 16:45:22 CET—Thu 2018-11-29 10:10:07 CET
-2 646787bd244d4230a5986f00207c1e8c Sun 2019-02-24 19:50:23 CET—Tue 2019-02-26 22:49:29 CET
-1 c922041a9a3847babd51ac79dd06923c Wed 2019-02-27 08:27:28 CET—Sun 2019-03-03 08:52:52 CET
 0 0aa03fbca4bf4976b922f9f77c63f65a Sun 2019-03-03 09:02:47 CET—Mon 2019-03-18 17:10:08 CET

# timestamps corresponds to universal timezone
user@node:~$ journalctl --list-boots --utc
-3 0f2fcb9569384a2aa2d5492505f86cda Tue 2018-11-27 15:45:22 UTC—Thu 2018-11-29 09:10:07 UTC
-2 646787bd244d4230a5986f00207c1e8c Sun 2019-02-24 18:50:23 UTC—Tue 2019-02-26 21:49:29 UTC
-1 c922041a9a3847babd51ac79dd06923c Wed 2019-02-27 07:27:28 UTC—Sun 2019-03-03 07:52:52 UTC
 0 0aa03fbca4bf4976b922f9f77c63f65a Sun 2019-03-03 08:02:47 UTC—Mon 2019-03-18 16:10:08 UTC
```

UTC timezone is **universal** that's why it is useful to avoid any daylight saving time misunderstanding issues.

From `journalctl` man page :

```
       --list-boots
           Show a tabular list of boot numbers (relative to the current boot), their IDs, and the timestamps of the first and last message pertaining to the boot.
```

PS : in case you have only one line returned by `journalctl`, just create folder `/var/log/journal` to enable multiple on-disk journal retention

Comment: Nice! Works, I  get the correct time: "Mon 2019-03-18 08:38:11 CET—Mon 2019-03-18 17:01:44 CET" and `last reboot` is still wrong by one hour: " 09:38 - 17:01"

Answer (score 0):

Grepping rsyslog stsrt/stops from /var/log/messages would likely suit your needs as that’s one of the first things to start and last things to stop on shutdown.